# Chrome reports Java plugin outdated

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, jre

I've just installed the latest version of JRE (7u5) and Chrome still reports that it's outdated. When I go to `chrome://plugins/`, it shows the following line for Java:

> Java - Version: 1.7.0_05 Download Critical Security Update

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start Chrome with a key

```
google-chrome --allow-outdated-plugins
```

But it is a bug, that will be fixed soon, I hope

Comment: Has this been reported as a bug? If so, do you have a link to the bug report?

Comment: I did not report it myself. But this bug is so obvious, that it will be noticed.
I saw this
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-bugs/X90hRNmiUVE

Comment: I installed OpenJDK in the end and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug, it says it would be fixed on next release.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138386

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-oracle-java7-jdk7-jre7-firefox-chrome-plugin

Ubuntu. Oracle Java 7.

Install the Oracle JDK 7.

Install the Oracle JRE 7.

Install the Firefox/Chrome Oracle Java 7 plugin

The latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

Access directory:

```
# cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

Create a link to the folder we just created:

```
# ln -s /opt/java/jre1.7.0_10/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

Reopen browser.